# Control a barcode scanner's beeper and LEDs in software

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

Does anybody know of any barcode scanners whereby their built-in LED and beeper can be controlled through software by sending commands TO the scanner?

My software application requires that the user be notified when the barcode they have scanned is not listed in our database. I would like to send a command to the scanner instructing it to beep twice and show it's red LED (for example).

Has anybody come across this or know any search terms I can use to find more information?

Many thanks,

Ross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say most non-HID scanners support allowing the application to confirm scanned data.

For instance, Socket CHSs support three different confirmation modes:

**Device** - In device mode, the scanner beeps/flashes/rumbles (ACKs) when it successfully decodes a barcode.

**ScanAPI** - Scanner ACKs when the scanned data was successfully received by the SDK (ie Bluetooth didn't drop the data)

**App** - The app notifies the scanner if the scan was "good".

You can read about the confirmation modes (bottom of pg 76-78) and notifying the scanner (pg 105) in the [ScanAPI docs](http://www.socketmobile.com/support/downloads/sdk/ScanAPI.pdf).

I believe you may even be able to change the confirmation tones and volume. I'll post an edit, if I find the docs for that.

*Full discolsure:* I am a consultant to Socket Mobile, Inc.